# React code is not visible properly in gitHub repository

Tags: reactjs, github, repository

I uploaded a react app on github repo and after pushing the code, I am seeing a new static folder instead of public and src folders, and the code is non readable in the repo.
https://github.com/Rohitkumar123github/random-suggestion-using-api
It will be easier if someone visit and see it.

I am new to github and i saw some videos on github hosting websites and when i tried to host my website i am seeing this static folder in my main branch instead of public and src. I want to use github to show my project source code and a running website to potential hires. But the source code is non readable right now.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the src, public, and other folders that you said in the .gitignore file? check this file, those folders mustn't be in the .gitignore file;
and check out that did you add those folders to the git stage before committing? (git add -A)